# loss increase fine-tuning caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, loss

I have a classification problem of 280 classes with ~278,000 images.
I do fine-tuning based on the model GoogleNet (bvlc_googlenet in caffe) using quick_solver.txt.
My solver is as follows:

```
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 4000
test_initialization: false
display: 40
average_loss: 40
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "poly"
power: 0.5
max_iter: 800000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0002
snapshot: 20000
```

During training I use the batch size of 32, and the test batch 32 too. I just relearn from scratch three layers loss1/classifier loss2/classifier and loss3/classifier by renaming them. I set the global learning rate 0.001, i.e. 10 times less than the one used in training from scratch. The last three layers however still get the learning rate 0.01.

Logfile of the very first iterations:

```
I0515 08:44:41.838122  1279 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 40, loss = 9.72169
I0515 08:44:41.838163  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss1/loss1 = 5.7261 (* 0.3 = 1.71783 loss)
I0515 08:44:41.838170  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #1: loss2/loss1 = 5.65961 (* 0.3 = 1.69788 loss)
I0515 08:44:41.838173  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #2: loss3/loss3 = 5.46685 (* 1 = 5.46685 loss)
I0515 08:44:41.838179  1279 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 40, lr = 0.000999975
```

Until the 100,000-th iteration, my net obtains 50% top-1 accuracy and ~80% top-5 accuracy:

```
I0515 13:45:59.789113  1279 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 100000, Testing net (#0)
I0515 13:46:53.914217  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: loss1/loss1 = 2.08631 (* 0.3 = 0.625893 loss)
I0515 13:46:53.914274  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss1/top-1 = 0.458375
I0515 13:46:53.914279  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #2: loss1/top-5 = 0.768781
I0515 13:46:53.914284  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #3: loss2/loss1 = 1.88489 (* 0.3 = 0.565468 loss)
I0515 13:46:53.914288  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #4: loss2/top-1 = 0.494906
I0515 13:46:53.914290  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #5: loss2/top-5 = 0.805906
I0515 13:46:53.914294  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #6: loss3/loss3 = 1.77118 (* 1 = 1.77118 loss)
I0515 13:46:53.914297  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #7: loss3/top-1 = 0.517719
I0515 13:46:53.914299  1279 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #8: loss3/top-5 = 0.827125
```

At the 119,00-th iteration everything is still normal

```
I0515 14:43:38.669674  1279 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 119000, loss = 2.70265
I0515 14:43:38.669777  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss1/loss1 = 2.41406 (* 0.3 = 0.724217 loss)
I0515 14:43:38.669783  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #1: loss2/loss1 = 2.38374 (* 0.3 = 0.715123 loss)
I0515 14:43:38.669787  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #2: loss3/loss3 = 1.92663 (* 1 = 1.92663 loss)
I0515 14:43:38.669798  1279 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 119000, lr = 0.000922632
```

Right after that the loss suddenly raise, i.e. equal to the initial loss ( from 8 to 9),

```
I0515 14:43:45.377710  1279 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 119040, loss = 8.3068
I0515 14:43:45.377751  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss1/loss1 = 5.77026 (* 0.3 = 1.73108 loss)
I0515 14:43:45.377758  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #1: loss2/loss1 = 5.76971 (* 0.3 = 1.73091 loss)
I0515 14:43:45.377763  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #2: loss3/loss3 = 5.70022 (* 1 = 5.70022 loss)
I0515 14:43:45.377768  1279 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 119040, lr = 0.000922605
```

And the net cannot reduce that loss long after the sudden change happened

```
I0515 16:51:10.485610  1279 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 161040, loss = 9.01994
I0515 16:51:10.485649  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss1/loss1 = 5.63485 (* 0.3 = 1.69046 loss)
I0515 16:51:10.485656  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #1: loss2/loss1 = 5.63484 (* 0.3 = 1.69045 loss)
I0515 16:51:10.485661  1279 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #2: loss3/loss3 = 5.62972 (* 1 = 5.62972 loss)
I0515 16:51:10.485666  1279 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 161040, lr = 0.0008937
```

I rerun the experiment two times and it just repeat exactly at the iteration 119040-th. For further information, I did data shuffling in creating the LMDB database. And I used this database to train a VGG-16 (step learning rate policy, max 80k iterations, 20k iters per step) without any problem. With VGG I obtain 55% top-1 accuracy.

Anybody meet a similar problem to mine?

Comment: decrease the learning rate

Comment: Maybe. But at the first 100k iterations the network learns very well with lr 0.01 for fc layers and 0.001 for other layers. If lr is too high it will not learn anything from the beginning .